# Can't see file directory of USB drive

Tags: windows-10, usb-storage

I have a new Dell XPS 13 laptop with Win 10. I have a USB hard drive that was plugged in to a Macbook Pro. I've now plugged it into the Dell. I cannot see the file directory. Win10 recognizes it (WD My Book USB) and it says it wants to initialize. I think that would cause all the data on the drive to be erased, wouldn't it?

What to I need to do?

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Disk Info via OS X]

Comment: What file system?

Comment: On the USB Drive? I don't know. Whatever it came with I guess. How do I determine this?

Comment: It’s sort of important and makes a huge difference. Can you determine that then update your question?

Comment: Added a screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your drive is formatted in [HFS+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus), the standard apple external drive format.  This can show up as [Mac OS Extended (Journaled)](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2007/05/pick-the-right-file-system-for-your-macs-internal-or-external-storage/) in the Mac disk info utility. For a drive to be compatable with both Mac and PC products, use a FAT based format, like [ExFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) or FAT32.  That doesn't help you now, or answer the question you asked.

There are several software products available to read HFS+ on Windows, with a varying level of polish.

- HFSExplorer is free and somewhat clunky, but provides read-only access and is easy to install and use.
- The drivers used in bootcamp can be manually installed for free as well - https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-hfs-windows-driver-download.1368010/
- MacDrive has come highly recommended for easy and reliable integration, but it is not free (as in beer) software.

Comment: Added a screen shot of disk info from the Mac. It says the format is Mac OS Extended (Journaled).

Comment: Added a reference showing Mac OS Extended (Journaled) as the same as HFS+, which wasn't clear.